# Why can't I subscript a Dictionary<String, Int> with a String?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I have a dictionary of type `Dictionary<String, Int>` and I'm trying to subscript it with a `String`.  I get the error
`Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<String, Int>' with an index of type 'String'`

Here is the whole method.  I am running Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.4), but I have also tried it and the same error occurs in Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7b4).

Here is the whole method:

```
override func isSatisfied<String, Int>(assignment: Dictionary<String, Int>) -> Bool {
        // if all variables have been assigned, check if it adds up correctly
        if assignment.count == variables.count {
            if let s = assignment["S"], e = assignment["E"], n = assignment["N"], d = assignment["D"], m = assignment["M"], o = assignment["O"], r = assignment["R"], y = assignment["Y"] {
                let send: Int = s * Int(1000) + e * Int(100) + n * Int(10) + d
                let more: Int = m * Int(1000) + o * Int(100) + r * Int(10) + e
                let money: Int = m * 10000 + o * 1000 + n * 100 + e * 10 + y
                if (send + more) == money {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }

        // until we have all of the variables assigned, the assignment is valid
        return true
    }
```

The problem line is if let s = assignment["S"]

Also here is the sourcecode repository:
https://github.com/davecom/SwiftCSP

And here is the specific file: 
https://github.com/davecom/SwiftCSP/blob/master/SwiftCSP/SwiftCSPTests/SendMoreMoneyTests.swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
func isSatisfied<String, Int>(assignment: Dictionary<String, Int>) -> Bool {
                 ^===    ^===
```

You have defined this function as generic, with two placeholders called `String` and `Int`.  These will mask the regular types.  Delete them, as this probably isn’t what you want.

It’s usually easier, when something strange like this happens, to reduce the case down to just show the problem.  I didn’t spot what was wrong until I tried trimming your function down to basically this:

[image]

(p.s. `[String:Int]` is shorthand for `Dictionary<String,Int>`)

Comment: What a silly oversight, thank you for the reply.  Is there a way to override a generic method with specific types?

Comment: Don’t think so – if you think about what this means, you aren’t really overriding the method – if a function takes a generic parameter (say, a totally unconstrained parameter), and you are saying in a subclass’s override “this only takes strings”, then you aren’t creating a version of the function that could be invoked instead of the base type’s function. What if the caller passed in an integer?

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I'll need to find a new design pattern.  I'm finding Swift's generics a serious impediment to porting this constraint satisfaction framework I'd previously built in Python and Dart.  Maybe I just don't understand them well enough!